# App doesn't recognize moved OBB file to SD even though 'Obb on SD' Xposed module is installed

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, xposed-framework

I'm trying to move the OBB files of some of my games to my SD card to free some internal storage space.

I looked for solutions and found the [Obb on SD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.smartmadsoft.xposed.obbonsd) Xposed module, which says that "just enable module, reboot and move obb's to SD card (to same folder: Android/obb) - that's that." My device is already rooted and has the Xposed Framework installed. So I just downloaded and enabled the module and rebooted.

I'm looking to move Plants vs Zombies 2's OBB file which is around 600 MB, to the SD card. I've updated the game in Google Play Store and then started it to verify that it is fully updated and doesn't need to download anything.

I then moved the `com.ea.game.pvz2_row` directory (which contains the OBB file) in `/storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/` to `/storage/sdcard1/Android/obb/` using Amaze File Manager in root explorer mode. I rebooted the device and then I ran Plants vs Zombies 2 but upon starting, it started downloading resources of around ~600 MB (which is probably the directory I moved).

**How do I make Plants vs Zombies 2 recognize the moved OBB file in the SD card?**

Details:

- Device: Lenovo A3300-HV
- Android version: KitKat 4.4.2
- The device is rooted. SU management app is SuperSU.
- I already did the 'KitKat SD Card' fix and I have other apps that write to the SD card without any issues.
- The `/storage/sdcard0/` directory despite its name, is actually internal storage. This device has only one physical SD card and it is at `/storage/sdcard1/`.
- Obb on SD details:

  - 'Data On SD' is unchecked
  - Play Store Hooks is unchecked (I also
    tried checking but it doesn't seem to affect the issue)
  - Detect SD on
    Android 5/6 is grayed-out and can't be toggled (says 'No path found')
  - Internal Path says "Detected: `/storage/emulated/0`".